# Python remove dynamically elements of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text

```
TextTextlkwhcuiachjwhdehwkjfchjwfbhjwvfbgAGE18 hjweghwvf wffguh wygfyugf hAGE29 kjefrhjefherbfhjefb AGE30
```

How can I make it become

```
TextTextlkwhcuiachjwhdehwkjfchjwfbhjwvfbg hjweghwvf wffguh wygfyugf h kjefrhjefherbfhjefb
```

?
So replacing AGEXXX with nothing?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what regexes are for.

```
import re
re.sub(r'AGE\d+', '', my_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `re` library. It's Python's version of Regex:

```
import re
new_string = re.sub(r'AGE\d{2,3}', '', string)
```

Where `string` is your input and `new_string` is the string without "AGEXXX"

Answer (score 0):

`str` behave similar to `list`s in some aspects:

```
string = "TextTextlkwhcuiachjwhdehwkjfchjwfbhjwvfbgAGE18 hjweghwvf wffguh wygfyugf hAGE29 kjefrhjefherbfhjefb AGE30"
word = "AGE"
extra_chars = 2

while word in string:
    string = string[:string.index(word)] + string[string.index(word)+len(word)+extra_chars:]
```

This would work as a simple way of doing it, for more complex solutions default to `re` module